# Styling a Listview with a gridview in it

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I tried to style my listview template, which contains a gridview. I tried to do it using an ItemsPresenter and it works fine but my gridview's header disappears.

What should i use to preserve my header?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Edit : My Listview

```
<ListView Name="findReplaceView" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FindAndReplaceItems}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
      <GridViewColumn Header="Find" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Find}"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=helperField1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Replace" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Replace}"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=helperField2, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code for your `listview` and the `gridview` inside.

Comment: Added it, though I don't see why it's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't style the header part. This is how you should do it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- This is how your headers are presented -->
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView},Path=View.Columns}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="MidnightBlue">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="WhiteSmoke" 
                                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Header}"
                                                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    <!-- This is how your items are presented -->
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Grid.Row="1"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the above code there are 2 `Grid.RowDefinitions` with `height="Auto"` and `height="*"` the first one is the area (i.e. the top row) that represents the header part and the second one is the remaining area that contains your `ItemsPresenter` and determines how your items are presented.

---

**Edit**

Since this is suppose to be a general style for a `ListView` that it's columns are already defined in some `ListView.View`, I thought using an `ItemsControl` for the headers part would make your style quite flexible. I modified my code sample accordingly in which the headers part is an `ItemsControl` with horizontal orientation that it's `ItemsSource` is bound to `ListView.View.Columns`. This way columns count in the style will depend on columns count in your `ListView`. Also the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` is a `TextBlock` that it's text is bound to the header of the respective column, therefore columns header in the style will be the same as columns headers in your `ListView`.

Comment: This way locks the header names to always be the same thing though. Any way to make that flexible?

Comment: you can use binding to get the headers from `ListView.View` like this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView},Path=View.Columns[0].Header}"` however you still have to specify the column's count in your style.

Comment: Close enough, thnx for the help